# Order data frame on two columns based on unique values

Tags: r

I have a R dataframe that I would like to order according to two columns (y - ascending and z - descending) based on the unique row names (x).

```
x   y   z
x1262   0.1222  0.5422
x1262   9.222   0.0233
x1262   1.2282  1.7453
x1263   0.1111  0.3739
x1263   0.3223  2.3288
x1264   0.9222  0.1122
x1265   0.3333  0.3367
```

I will like to have this dataframe:

```
x   y   z
x1262   9.222   0.0233
x1262   1.2282  1.7453
x1262   0.1222  0.5422
x1263   0.3223  2.3288
x1263   0.1111  0.3739
x1264   0.9222  0.1122
x1265   0.3333  0.3367
```

Here's my attempt which is not doing the job:

```
df[order(df$y,-df$z, decreasing = TRUE) %in% unique(rank(df$x)), ]
```

Can someone help please?
Thanks

Comment: Apologies! I forgot to add the code. I meant elements in column x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include column x in your `order` function to sort within the x id, and then use `-y` to sort decreasing in y.

```
dat[with(dat, order(x, -y, z)),]
      x      y      z
2 x1262 9.2220 0.0233
3 x1262 1.2282 1.7453
1 x1262 0.1222 0.5422
5 x1263 0.3223 2.3288
4 x1263 0.1111 0.3739
6 x1264 0.9222 0.1122
7 x1265 0.3333 0.3367
```

Note that if the x column was in some special order and you wanted to preserve that order then this code would not work unless you first changed the factor levels to encode the desired order.

Answer (score -1):

Does this work for you?

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
 arrange(x, desc(y))
```